# Flex-wrap combined with max-height working diffrently on desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, navbar

I am currently trying to create a dropdown like search bar inside a navbar.

This is my navbar:

[image: This is my navbar]

I read some documentations and found out that using max-height and flex-wrap, I can create a simple and animated dropdown navbar.

My problem is that on mobile, the navbar does not fully extend to full height.
See this:

[image: this]

expected result:

[image: here]

This is my code for the navbar which is inside and flex parent with flex direction column

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 56px;
  max-height: 56px;
  overflow: hidden;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;

  padding: 0.75rem 2rem;
  background-color: var(--clr-bg);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;

  transition: max-height 100ms ease-in;
}

.navbar.expanded {
  max-height: 140px;

  transition: max-height 100ms ease-out;
}


/* This is the search bar */
.navbar-search-container {
  order: 2;

  width: 100%;
  height: var(--navbar-button-size);

  margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  background-color: var(--clr-text);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML code:

```
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="navbar-logo-container">
          <img className="navbar-logo" src={logo} alt="Logo" />
        </div>
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className="navbar-nav-item button-search">
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
            <a onClick={expandSearch} className="navbar-icon-button">
              <Search />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar-nav-item">
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
            <a className="navbar-icon-button">
              <Plus />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar-nav-item">
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
            <a className="navbar-icon-button">
              <Star />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar-nav-item">
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
            <a className="navbar-icon-button">
              <Menu />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="navbar-search-container">
          <div className="navbar-search">
            <Search />
            <input name="navbar-search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search for stock" />
          </div>
          <div className="navbar-search-results"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <main>
        <div className="main-container">
          <div className="main-menu-container">
            <div className="main-menu"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="main-content"></div>
        </div>
      </main>
```

Comment: bit hard to find out what the problem is without the html code.

Comment: Forgot that, had it in my clipboard. Added it now

Comment: Have you checked that all your CSS variables are set somewhere (particularly in this case the navbar height) - who sets them?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from what you provided what the problem is. It could be a z-index issue, or some other CSS code not included that's interefering